# R unsupported conversion from 'CP1,254' to ' '

Tags: r, rstudio

I am writing a program on `R studio`. My program runs well on `R studio` but, when I try to run it using `.bat` command, it gives me the following error:

> Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :    unsupported
>   conversion from 'CP1,254' to '' Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval
>   -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> source -> file Execution halted

The whole `run.r.Rout` file can be found below :

```
> require(shiny)
Loading required package: shiny
> folder_address = '~//app_v2'
> runApp(folder_address, launch.browser = TRUE)

Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Warning: package 'lubridate' was built under R version 3.4.4

Attaching package: 'lubridate'

The following object is masked from 'package:base':

    date

Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  unsupported conversion from 'CP1,254' to ''
Calls: runApp ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> source -> file
Execution halted
```

Am I missing anything here? The solution must be simple but I just cannot figure it out. Could this be related to `lubridate` package usage? Again, my program runs well on R studio, but giving error when I run it on the terminal.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though some part of the code thinks your current file encoding is `"CP1,254"`, which isn't a real encoding.  You can see the full list of encodings that R knows about using `iconvlist()`.  On my system, that includes `"CP1254"`,
i.e. "code page 1254", used on Windows in a Turkish locale.

So you'll need to figure out where that comma came from.  Maybe some code queries the code page, and inserts a `formatC`-style `big.mark`?

Comment: Sir, thank you so much. One of my `source()` functions were actually containing `('~/AppMain/App_v2/File.R', encoding = 'CP1,254') ` instead of `encoding = 'CP1254'`. Which is what was causing the error. Now my `.bat` file works well.